# Rails-api authentications for Facebook SDK iOS connect?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm planning to use rails-api for providing JSON API for iOS mobile application to consume. The process:

1. User open the mobile app
2. User taps on Facebook connect
3. Mobile app get fb_access_token and post it to API server to identify the user
4. API server get user profile on Facebook by using fb_access_token
5. API server either create and look up the user, then response with a api_token for this particular user
6. Mobile app use the api_token response for all communication afterward.

Which authentication should be the best option for this app? oAuth2 or BasicAuth? I tried rails-api with doorkeeper, but it doesn't work out of the box because doorkeeper need some assets.

Answer (score 4):

I am doing a basic authentication for this integrated with devise.

First i get the post parameters from the mobile application (the access_token and other stuff).

Then I use open-api to get the user details from facebook:

```
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="
    begin
      content = open(URI.encode(url + params[:user][:access_token]))
    rescue OpenURI::HTTPError #with this I handle if the access token is not ok
      return render :json => {:error => "not_good_access_token" }
    end
```

Now Facebook returns the response

```
  status = content.status[0]
  content = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(content)

  if status == "200"
    #get the email and check if the user is already in the database. If there is not email, check by the facebook id
    #If the user exists return the user. If the user does not exists create new
```

Hope this helps

Than you can user the same code also for google, just change the url to "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token="

Comment: After you create a user, how do you create api key? and how to use api key afterward in your basic authentication?

Comment: I don't need the api key. I get the access_token from the mobile device (there I user the api key and secret to get the user access code). On the server I store the data that I get from Facebook and on the next access_token submit I just check if the user already exists in the database. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: I know client id and secret to access FB, but after you get access_token from the mobile and sent to server. Then server check to create a user or use existing one. What did you response back to mobile? And after user logged in, so all communications between mobile and server, do you still use access_token that you get from facebook on mobile or do you use your own key/code to identify user?

Comment: I have this a little customized, but I send back to the mobile the user_id and a secure_code (that I generate myself)...All other comunication inside the application is connected via the user_id and validated with the secure code....I use the access_token only when the user logins with Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

I'd give [omniauth-facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) at try, as it uses OAuth2 and is pretty easy to use. All omniauth strategies are rails middleware, so you just need to add `gem 'omniauth-facebook'` to your gemfile and add the following to `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` and you will be able to use `/auth/facebook` to log in via facebook and `/auth/facebook/callback` to create the user session (you might want to alter the :display key-value as pop-ups in mobile might not be aesthetically pleasing):

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
           :scope => 'email,user_birthday,read_stream', :display => 'popup'
end
```

The facebook auth token will be in the `request.env['omniauth.auth'][:credentials][:token]` that gets returned to your callback endpoint, which you can integrate into your mobile authentication strategy. see the above link and the [omniauth main page](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) for more details.

Comment: I know omniauth, but I feel it's more like for web client app. What I need to figure out the solution on how to secure my API.

Comment: Actually, it's just Rails middleware and works very well with Rails-API, regardless of whether the api is consumed via desktop or mobile. Check out this repo: https://github.com/toddlee/rails-omniauth-rest-api-server